# Spring Tools Suite and Gradle - Setup to use correct resources from inside STS

Tags: gradle, spring-tool-suite

I have a Spring Boot Gradle project setup in Spring Tools Suite (3.7.2 RELEASE) with the following source folders:

```
- src/integration-test/java
- src/integration-test/resources 
- src/main/java
- src/main/resources
- src/test/java
- src/test/resources`
```

Whenever I run the application or unit tests from within STS, I see that STS is using the resources found under `src/integration-test/resources`.

I see a duplicate resource warning in STS for files which exist in all 3 resource source folders. For example, I have an application.properties in all 3 source folders and I see following:

```
The resource is a duplicate of src/integration-test/resources/application.properties and was not copied to the output folder
```

If I run the application as a JAR or unit tests/integration tests from the command line (via gradle build), everything seems to use the correct resources. This makes me believe it is a problem with how STS/Eclipse is handling gradle.

**Does anybody know of how I can configure STS to use the correct resource source folders when using gradle?**

I think my problem may be related to (or the same as?) [Spring Boot incorrectly loads test configuration when running from eclipse+gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817251/spring-boot-incorrectly-loads-test-configuration-when-running-from-eclipsegradl?lq=1), https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3882, https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1777

I also tried the solution found here, but that seems to only fix Maven builds:
[Spring Tool Suite finds spring-boot integration test configuration and does not start main application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30123790/spring-tool-suite-finds-spring-boot-integration-test-configuration-and-does-not?lq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think my problem may be related to...

Yes, it is related but in my opinion not the same. That problem is caused by the runtime classpath being incorrect. This problem is an error coming from the eclipse project builder so it is a compile-time issue.

The problems are closely related though. Depending on your point of view, you could say they are the same (incorrect mixing of test and compile-time classpaths).

Here, specifically, the problem is that the eclipse builder tries to copy all the resources it finds in source folders to the project's single output folder. Each source folder has a 'application.properties'. The builder warns that it could not copy some of them because one would overwrite the other.

I think there may be a solution for this problem. But it is a solution that really should come from Gradle + ( BuildShip | STS Gradle Tooling) than from you.

It is possible in Eclipse to configure each source-folder individually to target a specific outputfolder. Maven + M2E are doing this correcty, but Gradle + (BuildsShip | STS Gradle Tooling) combdos do not.

For example this is what maven puts into the eclipse .classpath file when it configures a test resources folder:

```
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/resources">
         <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
         </attributes>
     </classpathentry>
```

Notice how it explicitly sets the output folder for that entry (to something different from the project's default output folder).

You may be able to address the problem yourself by modifying the .classpath for a gradle project in a similar way. Either by doing it manually or from your build.gradle.

I'm not sure this is worth it however as you will then likely still get hit by the runtime classpath issue (since these folders will still be added to your runtime classpath, your runtime classpath will end-up with two appication.properties resources, one which will 'shadow' the other. See: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=482315)

I would say, the right thing to do is [add a comment](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=482315#c8) to the issue I linked, and hope they fix it soon as there is only so much you can do yourself by hacking the build.gradle file to modify the .classpath (this can not solve the runtime classpath issue, but in order to solve the runtime classpath issue, they would have to configure source folders to target individual output folder similar to what m2e does).

Comment: I added a comment to the Eclipse bugzilla ticket referencing this question: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=482315#c8

Comment: Well I see you have been battling this runtime classpath issue for quite some time. Thanks for the verification of the problem. I thought there was definitely something wrong with my setup since finding related issues was not easy and I would see this problem right away when creating new projects. For now I am just running from outside of STS.

Answer (score 0):

I would add this as a comment to @Kris's answer but it's too long.

I have solved the runtime classpath issue by adding the code below to my `build.gradle` file.  The code generates an Eclipse launch configuration for the Spring Boot application class and includes only the `runtime` classpath (i.e. no test JARs).

My project uses the Gradle `'eclipse'` plugin to generate the Eclipse project files (which I then import into Eclipse).  Running the `eclipseClasspath` Gradle target will generate the launch file in the project's root directory.

```
def mainClassName = "com.example.MyApplication"
task eclipseApplicationLaunch {
    group "IDE"
    description "Generate an Eclipse launch configuration file for the Spring Boot application class"
}
eclipseApplicationLaunch << {
    def writer = new FileWriter("${mainClassName.substring(mainClassName.lastIndexOf(".")+1)}.launch")
    def xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(writer)
    xml.doubleQuotes = true 

    xml.launchConfiguration(type: "org.eclipse.jdt.launching.localJavaApplication") { 
        listAttribute(key:"org.eclipse.debug.core.MAPPED_RESOURCE_PATHS") {
            listEntry(value:"/${project.name}/src/main/java/${mainClassName.replace(".","/")}.java")
        }
        listAttribute(key:"org.eclipse.debug.core.MAPPED_RESOURCE_TYPES") {
            listEntry(value:"1")
        }
        listAttribute(key:"org.eclipse.jdt.launching.CLASSPATH") {
            listEntry(value:"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>\r\n<runtimeClasspathEntry containerPath=\"org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8/\" javaProject=\"${project.name}\" path=\"1\" type=\"4\"/>\r\n")
            listEntry(value:"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>\r\n<runtimeClasspathEntry path=\"3\" projectName=\"${project.name}\" type=\"1\"/>\r\n")
            configurations.runtime.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.each { artifact ->
                def filePath = artifact.file.canonicalPath.replace("\\","/")
                listEntry(value:"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>\r\n<runtimeClasspathEntry externalArchive=\"${filePath}\" path=\"3\" type=\"2\"/>\r\n")
            }
        }
        booleanAttribute(key:"org.eclipse.jdt.launching.DEFAULT_CLASSPATH", value:"false")
        stringAttribute(key:"org.eclipse.jdt.launching.MAIN_TYPE", value:"${mainClassName}")
        stringAttribute(key:"org.eclipse.jdt.launching.PROGRAM_ARGUMENTS", value:"--spring.profiles.active=local --spring.config.location=conf/")
        stringAttribute(key:"org.eclipse.jdt.launching.PROJECT_ATTR", value:"${project.name}")
        stringAttribute(key:"org.eclipse.jdt.launching.VM_ARGUMENTS", value:"-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true")
    }
    writer.close()
}
eclipseClasspath.dependsOn eclipseApplicationLaunch
```

I haven't modified the Eclipse `.classpath` file as per Kris' suggestion.  Instead, I have added `@Profile("test")` to my test application class and `@ActiveProfiles("test")` to my test classes.